# Continuously run bash script in Azure Container

Tags: bash, azure, docker-container, azure-container-service

I need to run a bash script continuously for indefinite time inside a docker container in Azure via Azure Container Instance service (ACI). My bash script has a while loop that keeps it running and Azure container has OnFailure Property to restart container if fails.

I see that after running Container for about 2 days, Container status is Running. However, the bash script that was running in foreground and sending logs in azure container console seems to be died and no longer sending logs to console. I also see it's not doing what it supposed to do.

How can I reliably keep this bash script running for indefinite time in Azure container?

The bash script which has internal while loop runs as below:

```
Commands
bash
my-while-loop-script.sh
```

Comment: How do you run the bash script in ACI? Just run it one time or run it as a cyclic task?

Comment: How do i run it as cyclic task ? @CharlesXu

Comment: Maybe you can try the `cron` in the Linux OS. It's a time task.

Comment: @Charles Xu Had to poke around a lot but finally found how to Running as a Cron and it worked.

Comment: That's great. Well, you can add the answer for others which looking for this.

Comment: Sure thing. When i found answer i was anyway going to put it but it slipped through cracks. I will put the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I replaced while loop inside `my-while-loop-script.sh` with a `crond` to execute a python application as a cron job. below is the line that executes a cron inside `my-while-loop-script.sh`. this line will execute `my-cron.cron` contents show below:

```
./busybox crond -f
```

To achieve that, I used `busybox 1.30.1` tools. To install busybox in your docker:

```
ADD busybox-1.30.1/ /busybox
WORKDIR /busybox
RUN make defconfig
RUN make
```

And, you also need to add cron settings to `crontabs` dir.

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
# Copy cron settings
ADD my-cron.cron /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

Sample `my-cron.cron` looks like just a normal cron file:

```
* * * * * python my-app.py
```